# Does mongoose findOne fetch a reference to the document or just value?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, reference

[Screenshot image] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bs5v.png)In line 103, findOne method is used which is fetching a document.
In the fetched document, when a field is changed(i.e added an item to the field "items" in this case),
and it is saved to the database again, does it get added as a new document or
it updates the original document that was fetched?

I thought that the save method was like insertOne.
I was expecting it to be saved as a new document but I think it is updating the original document?

I wonder if the fetched document is reference to the original document or just a copy of it;

Comment: `foundList` is one element with `name` equal to `listName`. If you need to create a new instance of it you need to create a new `List` object and set the properties to be equal to the retrieved element.

Comment: What I wanted to know more precisely is ... when foundList was updated(i.e added an item in its already existing field "items") and foundList.save() is called...how is it able to update the document in database... does foundList has refernce to the document in database? And if it does, lets say I did "let updatedList=foundList" "updatedList.items.push(newItem)"  "updatedList.save()"...will this 3 line of code do same thing as "foundList.items.push(newItem) " " foundList.save()" these 2 lines?

Comment: `foundList` is identified uniquely in the collection by its `_id` attribute. Which is an `ObjectId` type that `MongoDB` automatically generates.

Comment: Oh...So as long as _id is same, save() is going to just update the object in database with that id... thanks